# How to check if there is a value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
I have List of dictionaries:

[{
 'Make_Name': 'HONDA',
 'Model_Name': 'Accord'},
 {
 'Make_Name': 'HONDA',
 'Model_Name': 'Civic'},
 ....................
 {
 'Make_Name': 'HONDA',
 'Model_Name': 'Pilot'},
```

How to  check if a certain  Model_Name is in this list.

Accord --> True

ajejhc-->False

Comment: you can use a for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you store the wanted name as `car_model` you can do this:

```
print(car_model in [v['Model_Name'] for v in list_of_dicts])
>>> True # or False
```

there is a better option which is also more performant because it avoids iterating when one condition is met..

```
any(car_model  == v['Model_Name'] for v in list_of_dicts)
>>> True # or False
```

note this i removed the `[` `]` and now it is a generator so we avoid creating the whole list..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop with dict().values() method as below code

```
a_list = [{
    'Make_Name': 'HONDA',
    'Model_Name': 'Accord'},
    {
    'Make_Name': 'HONDA',
    'Model_Name': 'Civic'},
    {
    'Make_Name': 'Accord',
    'Model_Name': 'Pilot'}]

for dic in a_list:
    print('Accord' == dic['Model_Name'])
    #or
    #return 'Accord' == dic['Model_Name']
```

Comment: That would also print True if "Accord" is the Make_Name

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I will correct that. Thank you for mentioning it

Comment: instead of `in` do `==` because its not a list anymore it will allow values like `'Acc'`...

Comment: You are right it is a string now. But how it affect to the final result?

Comment: Ok I understood, string is a sequence also. I got the point. thank you so much. Learned something in today